# Was PyQGIS released with the first QGIS version?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, api

Is it correct that PyQGIS was introduced with QGIS 3.0, or was there a Python API from the beginning?

Comment: QGIS 2.*x* has PyQGIS too, without PyQGIS, no QGIS plugins could have been developed, and if you look at the plugins page for QGIS 2.*x* : https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/?sort=created_on , plugins had been developped since (at least) 2011.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the Python API was introduced earlier. The first stable release with QGIS 1.0 in 2009.

> At 1.0 we provide a stable API from which you can develop custom
> solutions in Python or C++.

See: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2009-January/005774.html

Digging deeper in the QGIS history you can find:

For the release of 0.11.0 they say:

> This release introduces several new features including python support
> and many new GRASS modules.

and in "Major changes in this release are:"

> separation of python support into its own library

See: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/announce/2008-July/000097.html

According to another source,

> Python support was first introduced in QGIS 0.9.

See: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html

---

As a conclusion one can say, the first stable release was introduced with QGIS 1.0 in 2009, but the development began earlier, likely with 0.9 in 2007 or with 0.11.0 in 2008 the latest, even though the keywords PyQGIS or API were not mentioned for 0.11.0 and 0.9.